# Cannot acces a disposed object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to change some of my linq codes to sp but in one my functions which is

```
private async Task getNodes()
{
    List<TreeViewNode> nodes = new List<TreeViewNode>();
    var activities = await _spConnections.GetActiveListBySpAsync(User.Identity.GetCookieUserCompId<int>());

    //Loop and add the Parent Nodes.
    foreach (var activity in activities)
    {
        var model1 = await _activitiesService.GetByIdWithFormsAsync(activity.ID);
        var model = model1.Forms.OrderBy(f => f.Order).ToList();
        var preformid = model1.PreFormId;

        nodes.Add(new TreeViewNode { id = activity.ID.ToString(), parent = "#", text = activity.Name });
        var Forms = await _spConnections.GetSpMainActiveFormListAsync(activity.ID);
        // Loop and add the Child Nodes.
        foreach (var form in Forms)
        {
            DigitalContentEnum enumType = EnumHelper<DigitalContentEnum>.Parse(form.Type);
            string typeName = EnumHelper<DigitalContentEnum>.GetDisplayValue(enumType);

            nodes.Add(new TreeViewNode { id = form.ActivitiesID.ToString() + "-" + form.ID.ToString(), parent = form.ActivitiesID.ToString(), text = form.Title + " <span class='text-danger'>(" + typeName + ") </span> "});
        }

        if (preformid != null)
        {
            var preformtags = await _activitiesService.GetByIdWithPreFormsAsync(preformid);
            var preformModel = preformtags.Forms.OrderBy(x => x.Order).ToList();

            foreach (var foorm in preformModel)
            {
                DigitalContentEnum enumType = EnumHelper<DigitalContentEnum>.Parse(foorm.Type);
                string typeName = EnumHelper<DigitalContentEnum>.GetDisplayValue(enumType);

                nodes.Add(new TreeViewNode { id = foorm.ActivitiesID.ToString() + "-" + foorm.ID.ToString(), parent = model1.ID.ToString(), text = foorm.Title + " <span class='text-danger'>(" + typeName + ") </span> " });
            }
        }
    }

    //Serialize to JSON string.
    var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nodes);
    ViewBag.Json = result;
}
```

So as you see var activities is being filled by running a sp and it does work
but when it reaches

```
var model1 = await _activitiesService.GetByIdWithFormsAsync(activity.ID);
```

The Error:

> Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
> Object name: 'Context'.

appears

activitesservice is my repository which the runs the following :

```
public async Task<Activity> GetByIdWithFormsAsync(long id)
{
    return await _activities.Include(x => x.Forms).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.ID == id);
}
```

and my sp is:

```
public async Task<List<Form>> GetSpMainActiveFormListAsync(long actId)
{
    var Check = new List<Form>();
    using (_unitOfWork)
    {
        using (var cmd = _unitOfWork.ExecuteCreateConnection())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SpGetMainActiveForm";
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            var param1 = cmd.CreateParameter();
            param1.ParameterName = "actId";
            param1.Value = actId;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);

            _unitOfWork.ExecuteOpenConnection();
            using (var result = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (result.HasRows)
                {
                    Check = (List<Form>)CommonFunctions.Conversions.MapToList<Form>(result);
                }
            }
            _unitOfWork.ExecuteCloseConnection();
        }
    }
    return Check;
}
```

UnitOfWork is my repository of my Context which is

```
public interface IUnitOfWork:IDisposable
{
    EntityEntry<TEntity> Entry<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class;
    void MarkAsChanged<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class;
    DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
    int SaveChanges(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess);
    int SaveChanges();
    void ExecuteSqlCommand(string query);
    DbCommand ExecuteCreateConnection();
    void ExecuteOpenConnection();
    void ExecuteCloseConnection();
    void ExecuteSqlCommand(string query, params object[] parameters);
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken());
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken());
}
```

and my context is:

```
public class Context : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
{
    public Context(DbContextOptions<Context> options)
    : base(options)
    {

    }
    public virtual DbSet<Admin> Admin { set; get; }
    public virtual DbSet<Activity> Activities { set; get; }
    public virtual DbSet<ActivityCategory> ActivityCategories { set; get; }
    public virtual DbSet<ActivitiesPic> ActivitiesPics { set; get; }
    public virtual DbSet<ActivityRecord> ActivityRecords { set; get; }
    public virtual DbSet<Answer> Answers { set; get; }
    public virtual DbSet<Company> Companies { set; get; }
    public virtual DbSet<Form> Form { set; get; }
    public virtual DbSet<NazerOrTarah> NazerOrTarah { set; get; }
    
    //Added in 1398/12/13
    public virtual DbSet<ReportDynamicTemplate> ReportDynamicTemplate { set; get; }
    public virtual DbSet<ReportTemplateForms> ReportTemplateForms { set; get; }

    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { set; get; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.HasDefaultSchema("dbo");
        builder.Entity<Activity>()
            .HasIndex(a => a.CompID);


        builder.Entity<ActivityRecord>()
            .HasIndex(a => new { a.ActivitiesID, a.NazerID });

        builder.Entity<Answer>()
            .HasIndex(a => new { a.ActRecordsID, a.FormID });

        builder.Entity<Form>()
            .HasIndex(a => new { a.ActivitiesID, a.ParentId });

        // it should be placed here, otherwise it will rewrite the following settings!
        foreach (var relationship in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys()))
        {
            relationship.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
        }

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }

    public void MarkAsChanged<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
    {
        Update(entity);
    }

    public void ExecuteSqlCommand(string query)
    {
        Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(query);
    }

    public DbCommand ExecuteCreateConnection()
    {
        return Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();
    }

    public void ExecuteOpenConnection()
    {
        Database.OpenConnection();            
    }
    public void ExecuteCloseConnection()
    {
        Database.CloseConnection();
    }
    public void ExecuteSqlCommand(string query, params object[] parameters)
    {
        Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(query, parameters);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?